# Sum Bucket aggregation for the buckets with certain keys

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using this to aggregate my documents by `type` field:

```
       "aggs": {
        "types": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "type"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "my_sum": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "price"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "total_sum": {
          "sum_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "types.my_sum"
          }
        }
      }
```

So in each bucket there is `my_sum` value (the sum of all the prices of documents with the same type as that bucket key), and `total_sum` is the sum of all this `my_sum` values. What I really need is to calculate the sum of `my_sum` values only when the key of bucket (`type`) is 1 or 2. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out elastic search aggregation [filtering values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_3) can solve my problem:

```
"aggs": {
    "types": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "type",
        "include": [
           1,
           2
         ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "my_sum": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "total_sum": {
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "types.my_sum"
      }
    }
  }
```